# Where can I find the two books of Weil on abelian varieties?

Tags: reference-request

They are "Sur les courbes algebriques ..." and "Varietes abeliennes et courbes algebriques", published by Hermann in 1948. Is there any link online for these old Hermann books?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are in Beijing, I think you can find these two books in the university library of Tsinghua (老馆闭架库).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the practical instruction.

Comment: @shenghao: The answer to your question about online links is almost certainly no, unless someone has scanned the documents and posted them (illegally no doubt).   Libraries or individuals with copies are usually the only source nowadays.   Weil among others published a lot of influential lecture notes, small monographs like the ones you mention, etc.   These aren't included in the 3 volume collected papers published by Springer years ago.   Future access is a big question, partly due to EU copyright laws.   Aside from that, Weil's language for algebraic geometry is now partly archaic.

Comment: This article by Raynaud, an appreciation of Weil's works, contains a brief summary of results in these books. ams.org/notices/199908/fea-raynaud.pdf 

Moreover it seems the first book contains a proof of the Riemann hypothesis for curves over finite fields based on the inequality of Castelnuovo-Severi.  This proof, apparently with modifications by Mattuck-Tate and Grothendieck  is ex. V.I.10 in Hartshorne, or Th. 10.8.5. of Kempf's Algebraic Varieties.